# Confused about function prologue

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, variadic-functions, calling-convention

I was looking at a dissasembly of the printf function (x86-64):
[image: Image of printf dissasembly].

And I am confused about the following lines:

```
mov    [rsp+_Format], rcx
mov    [rsp+arg_8], rdx
mov    [rsp+arg_10], r8
mov    [rsp+arg_18], r9
```

Any particular reason the arguments are saved into memory before rsp (and before the function frame I assume?).
Why aren't the registers' values saved into parameters with negative offsets, like var_18?

Comment: Greetings and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please do not post pictures of code.  Instead, [edit] your question and replace the picture with text.

Comment: To answer your question, look up *shadow space.*  The register arguments are spilled into the shadow space, making it easier to implement the variable argument list used by `printf`.

Comment: @fuz Hi sorry, will do.

So it is by design because the number of arguments can change?

Comment: Yes, correct.  The shadow space is there precisely for this reason.

Comment: Please don't add images of the code